# OnActionExecuting is not executing if reqest model is incorrect

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

When I call my service from a Swagger with the proper Json request `{"Token": "string", "Minutes": 0}`, `OnActionExecuting` is called. However, if I make a requst with missing parameters `{ "Token": "string", "Minutes": }` (missing number for `Minutes`), `OnActionExecuting` is not being.

More background information:
Web API project `AspNetCore project 2.2.0`

Controller that will receive request:

```
[HttpPost]
[ServiceFilter(typeof(ValidationAPIFilter))] 
[Route("ResetPendingTimeout")]
public IActionResult ResetTimeout([FromBody]ResetTimoutRequest resetTimoutRequest)

public class ValidationAPIFilter : ActionFilterAttribute {   
      public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) {}
```

`OnActionExecuting` is being used to validate parameters that are passed to `ResetTimeout(...)` action

```
public class ResetPendingTimoutRequest 
{
     public ResetPendingTimoutRequest();
     public string Token { get; set; }
     public long Minutes { get; set; }
}
```

Swagger result:

```
 {
  "Errors": {
    "Minutes": [
      "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: }. Path 'Minutes', line 5, position 0.",
      "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: }. Path 'Minutes', line 5, position 0."
    ]
  },
  "Title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "Status": 400,
  "traceId": "80000049-0000-f900-b63f-84710c7967bb"
}
```

Comment: Does your API method gets called at all in that case?

Comment: @Rahul No, is not being called at all.

Comment: What response code do you receive in Swagger?

Comment: @AdamGreene I just updated my original question with Swagger response. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Because **ModelBinding** middleware call before **ActionFilters** and when your model is not valid, your action filter doesn't run.

For this case you can use **MiddlewareFilter** because **MiddlewareFilter** run before **ModelBinding** and you can check the model in the **MiddlewareFilter** if model is not valid add `0` or `null` to `Minutes`.

in **MiddlewareFilter** you can change the request body.

This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#using-middleware-in-the-filter-pipeline-1) maybe helpful for you
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that is a valid request. I think if you are trying to achieve "I don't want any minutes property" with your request you need to leave the "minutes" property out all together. By doing this I believe that the value will come in as 0 for the long data type. If you make your data type nullable

```
public long? Minutes
```

and you leave the minutes property blank in your request it will come through as null.